# is it possible to add multiple snippets in one file of html.json in visual basic?

Tags: html, visual-studio, code-snippets

```
{
    "html":{
        "prefix": "html",
        "body": [
          "<!DOCTYPE html>",
          "<html lang='en'>",
          "<head>",
          "<meta charset='UTF-8'>",
          "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=' '>",
          "<title>",

          "</title>",       
          "</head>",
          "<body>",

          "</body>",
          "</html>",
        ],
        "description": "html"
   }
}

{
  "css-doodle": {
      "prefix": "css-doodle",
      "body":[ 
          "<script src='https://unpkg.com/css-doodle@0.7.2/css-doodle.min.js'></script>", 
          "<css-doodle>",
          "content" ,
          "</css-doodle>",   
      ],
      "description": "doodle",
  }
}
```

so above are the two snippets of html. But the latter one of css-doodle isnt working. Is there some mistake in the code or a specific way separate the two?

Answer (score 1):

I see it has been 8 months, so putting the answer here for others to come across. Your problem is that you have an end of file bracket after your description, and you are missing a comma. You also have a start of file bracket at the start of your second snippet.

Your code should look as follows:

```
{
    "html":{
        "prefix": "html",
        "body": [
          "<!DOCTYPE html>",
          "<html lang='en'>",
          "<head>",
          "<meta charset='UTF-8'>",
          "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=' '>",
          "<title>",

          "</title>",       
          "</head>",
          "<body>",

          "</body>",
          "</html>",
    ],
    "description": "html"
   },



  "css-doodle": {
      "prefix": "css-doodle",
      "body":[ 
          "<script src='https://unpkg.com/css-doodle@0.7.2/css-doodle.min.js'></script>", 
          "<css-doodle>",
          "content" ,
          "</css-doodle>",   
      ],
      "description": "doodle",
  }
}
```

Basically, for each code snipped you want to add, just place a comma after the snippet, and place the end of file bracket *just once*, at the end of the json. As you can see, subsequent snippets do not have a bracket before their name.

Hope this helps. I know I about tore my hair out trying to figure this out the first time.